# system.loadlibrary with libname as parameter

Tags: android, static, java-native-interface

I want to do a class that receives a libname as a parameter in constructor. Depending on that parameter different objects instanciated of this class have to load different dynamic libraries with a call to system.loadlibrary(libname). 
For example, object 1 loads library1 and object 2 load library 2 but the problem is both are loading the same library. Not sure is second call to loadlibrary is ignored or the second is overloading the first. 
Is there a way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Try Overriding Constructor of this Class [u are making] For each type library, Different parameter  type each time. if u are Restricted to only string as parameter, then use switch case inside constructor, hope u are using Java SE 7 or above.

Comment: I hava a string array with library names in this class. The constructor receives the position as parameter like this: system.loadlibrary(librariesarray[position]);. I make a test with two libraries and both are loaded (instruction executed) but in practice both object are using the same library.